# access another class thats called in a different class

Tags: java

I want to change a variable in a class that's already called in another class.

For example:

class A

```
public class classA{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        classB b = new classB();
        classC c = new classC();
        b.setX(10);
        c.printX();
}
```

class B

```
public class classB{
    public void setX(int i){
    classC c = new classC();     
    c.setX(i)                <------ this makes a new class so its changing this 
                           classes x variable and not the one i called in class a.
}
```

class C

```
public class classC{
    int x;

    public void setX(int i){
    x = i;
    }

    public void printX(){
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and the console returns null.

Basically, in class B I am making a new instance of class C but instead i want to use the same class that is called in class A, not class B.

BTW, this is an example code. Its the best I could simplify from what my other program does without pasting all my code on here.

okay, i solved it. i justed passed the class i used before to the other methods. i didnt know you could do that lol

Comment: Something went wrong with code formatting.

Comment: What's the point of `classB`'s setX? If it creates a new instance of classC and does nothing with it after calling classC's setX, there's no point. If you would change it to call classC's setX for a specific instance of classC, you can just call setX of that instance directly.

Comment: Can you use inheritance?  meaning: can somehow class A and B inherit from same parent object? if so, class C could be a static member of the parent class and then both could change the value of the inner instance w/o having to create a new instance. (note: I typically would not recommend this approach but w/o further explanation as to what you are trying to achieve, it's viable)

Comment: Instance of ClassC in ClassB is different from Instance of ClassC in ClassA.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass class C as a parameter:

```
public class classB{
        public void setXinClass(C cClass, int i){
            cClass.setX(i);
        }
```

Or if you want to hold a C class instance the whole lifetime of an object of class B you could hold a C class instance in class B:

```
public class classB{
    private C cClass = null;

    public classB(C cClass){
        this.cClass = cClass;
    }

    public void setXinClass(int i){
        this.cClass.setX(i);
    }
```

The second version is better if you make more operations on class C. If you use the C class reference all the time, then passing it every time as a parameter is less preferable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `classB` to execute methods of a specific instance of `classC` (I'm ignoring the example you provided, since it doesn't make much sense), you have to pass that instance of `classC` to `classB`. Either pass it to `classB`'s constructor, or define a method `setC` that would accept an instance of `classC` and store it in a member of `classB`.

In classB :

```
private classC c;
public classB (classC c) {
    this.c = c;
}

public void setC (classC c) {
    this.c = c;
}
```

Then you can call any method of `classC` for this instance.